# writeToFile working on simulator, but not on device

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator, plist

I have a plist which I am changing:

```
NSString *finalPath = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"KeyFrameFileByMovie.plist"];
NSMutableDictionary *keyFrameFileByMovie = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:finalPath];
[keyFrameFileByMovie setValue:keyFrameName forKey:movieName];
BOOL isOk = [keyFrameFileByMovie writeToFile:finalPath atomically:YES];
```

On the simulator isOk is 1 
on the device isOK is 0

I don't think it is a case sensative issue, because I have a getting code that works:

```
NSString *finalPath = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"KeyFrameFileByMovie.plist"];<br>
NSDictionary *plistData =[[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:finalPath] retain];
```

Why is does writeToFile fail on the device?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

iPhone application has very strict directory structure. Unfortunately the permissions on the device vs simulator are diferent. So the only problem here can be that you are not saving in the Documents directory but in the MainBundle dir.

In the example above, what is the path value?

Answer (score 4):

What's the path you're originally starting with? Remember, the iPhone is case-sensitive, but the Mac is (usually) not, so that might be tripping you up. I would log finalPath to the log in both cases, and visually verify they're the same.

Comment: This almost assuredly the issue.

Comment: I am sorry, I worked until very late...
 the isOk return 0 on device which means this is other problem

Answer (score 3):

Add "/" while appending the string

```
NSString *finalPath = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/KeyFrameFileByMovie.plist"];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *applicationDocumentsDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *storePath = [applicationDocumentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"default.txt"];
NSString *stringFilepath = [docPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"configlocaljson.json"];[replacedString writeToFile:stringFilepath atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
NSError * error = nil;
BOOL success = [replacedString writeToFile:stringFilepath atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
NSLog(@"Success = %d, error = %@", success, error);
```

Its work for me.